# traverse element inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html:

```
<div style="width: 260px;margin:25px 0 0 30px">
<input type="checkbox"  name="send_email" class="delete_followup" />Send email alerts
<input type="checkbox" value="delete" type="checkbox" />Send SMS alerts <button type="submit" name="delete" value="{{follower.id}}" class="delete_follower">Delete</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".delete_followup").click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
$(this).find(".delete_follower").show();           
});
```

I want to show the hidden button on clicking the `delete_followup` class.i TRIED WITH ABOVE jQuery but not working.

Comment: @Sergio yes,your answer and Cherniv answer working fine..Confused to accept the answer..

Comment: You can accept on and vote up the other :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try [`.nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$(this).nextAll(".delete_follower").show();
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/tw5XK/

Comment: Your solution is simple

Answer (score 1):

The `delete_follower` element is not a decedent of `delete_followup` element, it is a sibling element so instead of `find()` you need to use `siblings()`

```
$(".delete_followup").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings(".delete_follower").show();           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".delete_followup").click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).siblings(".delete_follower").show();
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(".delete_follower").hide();
    }
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rwrxC/)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to search downward into the div, when you already have a reference to the element you want. Making it way more complicated than it needs to be lol

```
$(".delete_followup").click(function(){
   $(this).show();           
});
```

Whenever you trigger off a click event, the actual element clicked on is passed through as the scope of the function. Since you are triggering off the click of ".delete_followup", that div is your element scope